# OneDrive API 'view.search' doesn't seem to work with Asian languages

Tags: onedrive

I'm trying to use OneDrive API search.

https://dev.onedrive.com/items/search.htm

It works great with English. I get relevant results from it. However, it doesn't with other languages (e.g. Japanese). I always get zero result.

Do I encode the keyword? Yes.

This query is,
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{id}/view.search?q=ドキュメント

Like this.
q=%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88

I checked search functionality on onedrive.live.com Web UI (the search box on the left top), it works fine. Looking at the traffic by Fiddler, it seems to be using different end point. So it seems an issue specific with the public API.

Is there anyone who encountered this and know any workaround? 
This is really a deal breaker to build app for many Asian countries, and it's a bit hard to believe this API has been broken like this so I'm sort of hoping there is a trick around this to make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we investigated your issue and did find something unexpected in the service. The fix has been deployed so hopefully your searches will now behave as expected.

Comment: Great! I just verified the issue is fixed. Thank you.